# Copying 0 bytes in cudaMemcpyAsync

Tags: cuda

I'm curious to know what happens if I set the parameter "count" in cudaMemcpyAsync to zero, i.e. cudaMemcpyAsync(dst, src, count, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream)? In my code, the function returns cudaSuccess, but is the copy still executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Err, yes, zero bytes *are* copied from source to destination.

But, since there's no distinction between copying and not copying for that particular size, it's irrelevant.

If you're asking if there's any sort of device-to-host communication for a zero-sized buffer, that's an implementation detail that is not specified (I wouldn't bet money on it though since it would be somewhat inefficient).

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful. I was wondering if there would be any communication between the host and device, e.g. interrupts or something similar, even though technically nothing is copied.

Comment: Does it matter? You can easily check the size yourself and not call the cudaMemcpy if you are worried about extra overhead.

Comment: The question is, will copying -1 bytes from host to device, copy 1 byte from device to host? :)